# How to read specific sheets from My XLS file in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

As of now i can read EXCEL file's all sheet.

```
e.msgbox("select Excel File")
updated_deleted_xls = e.fileopenbox()
book = xlrd.open_workbook(updated_deleted_xls, formatting_info=True)
openfile = e.fileopenbox()
for sheet in book.sheets():
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
for col in range(sheet.ncols):
thecell = sheet.cell(row, 0)
xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, 0)
xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
```

Comment: Use [`book.sheet_by_name()`](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.book.Book.sheet_by_name).

Answer (score 7):

If you open your editor from the desktop or command line, you would have to specify the file path while trying to read the file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'File path', sheet_name='Sheet name')
```

Alternatively, if you open your editor in the file's directory, then you could read directly using the panda library

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('KPMG_VI_New_raw_data_update_final.xlsx', sheet_name='Title Sheet')
df1 = pd.read_excel('KPMG_VI_New_raw_data_update_final.xlsx',sheet_name='Transactions')
df2 = pd.read_excel('KPMG_VI_New_raw_data_update_final.xlsx', sheet_name='NewCustomerList')
df3 = pd.read_excel('KPMG_VI_New_raw_data_update_final.xlsx', sheet_name='CustomerDemographic')
df4 = pd.read_excel('KPMG_VI_New_raw_data_update_final.xlsx', sheet_name='CustomerAddress')
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `Pandas`would be helpful ( the go-to package for data) :

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_excel('filname.xls', sheet = 0)
```

Edit: Since a lot of time has passed and pandas matured the arguemnts have change. So for pandas >1.0.0

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_excel('filname.xls', sheet_name = 0)
```

Comment: I get a TypeError that ```read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument `sheet```

Comment: @x89 well  a lot of time has passed and pandas matured  already - nowadays that thing is call `sheet_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `book.sheet_by_name()` to read specific sheets by their name from xls file.

```
for name, sheet_name in zip(filename, sheetnumber):  
  book = xlrd.open_workbook(name) 
  sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name) 
  for row in range(sheet.nrows): 
    for column in range(sheet.ncols):
      thecell = sheet.cell(row, 0) 
      xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, 0)
      xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
```

`filename` is the path to your xls file. Specify the sheet number you need to read in `sheetnumber`.

Alternatively, you could use `book.sheet_by_index()` and pass argument to return a specific sheet.
From docs:

> **sheet_by_index(sheetx)**
>
> Parameters: sheetx – Sheet index in range(nsheets)

For example:

```
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0) # returns the first sheet.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply theausome. I have 6 sheets in the excel file i would like to read sheet 1,2,3,5. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Use `book.sheet_by_index()` and pass argument. For example: `book.sheet_by_index(0)` returns the first sheet. Read through this for more info https://dzone.com/articles/reading-excel-spreadsheets

Answer (score 0):

You can use either **book.sheet_by_name()** or **book.get_sheet()**

**Example** using get_sheet()

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(updated_deleted_xls, formatting_info=True)
sheet = book.get_sheet(0) #Gets the first sheet.
```

**Example** using sheet_by_name()

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook(updated_deleted_xls, formatting_info=True)
sheet_names = book.sheet_names()

xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])
```

**[MoreInfo](https://blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2014/06/16/reading-excel-with-python-xlrd/)** on getting sheet by sheet_by_name