# Revisit the question "How to read specific sheets from My XLS file in Python"

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I met the same question as the following discussion:
[How to read specific sheets from My XLS file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663698/how-to-read-specific-sheets-from-my-xls-file-in-python)

I used the method mentioned in that discussion in my codes

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd


folder = r'C:\Users\Denny\Desktop\Work\no_solution'
files = os.listdir(folder)
dfs = {}
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        dfs[file[:-5]] = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file), sheet_name='Z=143', header = None, skiprows=[0], usecols = "B:M")
```

Here I have two sheets, the first one is called "sheet" and the other, "Z=143". So in the codes, I added **sheet_name='Z=143'**.

[image]

However, it shows the following error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Denny\\Desktop\\Work\\no_solution\\~$T2405.6Mhz.xlsx'
```

I tried to put "Z=143" at different position; however, it failed.

How can I overcome this problem?   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is just with your looped `if` statement

```
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx') and not file.startswith('~'):
        dfs[file[:-5]] = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(folder,file), sheet_name='Z=143', header = None, skiprows=[0], usecols = "B:M")
```

The condition I added makes sure that you don't read the temporary files excel creates for open files

Answer (score 1):

It could be because the file was open when you tried to run the script? 
Try closing it and running again